# Multithreading in JavaFX data binding int to Task value

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, data-binding

I am fairly new to multi-threading and have run into a bit of difficulty getting tasks to work within my application.

I have a file browser that allows users to select file(s) to be imported and while this import is occurring I am trying to update a progress bar at the bottom of the screen. However, I am trying to avoid making the bar "indeterminate" for the import process but instead fill with the actual import progress.

In order to accomplish this, I have created 2 tasks, 1 to get a total count of the files to be imported from the selected items in the file browser tree and a 2nd to actually import the songs and update the progress bar based on a simple equation using the total count from first task.

**However, I'm unsure of how to get the int value from the first task into the the second task.**

This also brings up a few additional questions, first about just getting things to work and secondly about the performance aspect of my design.

**Controller Class**

```
@FXML
private void handleImportButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    new Thread(getSelectedFilesLeafCountTask).start();
    new Thread(importSongsTask).start();
}
```

**Get Leaf Count Task**

```
@Component
public class GetSelectedFilesLeafCountTask extends Task<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private FileBrowserController fileBrowserController;

    @Autowired
    private FooterController footerController;

    private Integer leafCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            footerController.getTaskProgressIndicator().setProgress(ProgressBar.INDETERMINITE);
            footerController.getTaskLabel().setText("Indexing Files");
        });

        getSelectedItemsLeafCount(fileBrowserController.getFileBrowser().
            getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

        return leafCount;
    }

// Recursively counts the leaves within a single or group of Files 

    private void getSelectedItemsLeafCount(List<TreeItem<File>> files) {

        for(TreeItem<File> f : files) {
            if(f.isLeaf()) {
                leafCount++;
            }else {
                getSelectedItemsLeafCount(f.getChildren());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Import Songs Task**

```
@Component
public class ImportSongsTask implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    FileBrowserController fileBrowserController;

    @Autowired
    FooterController footerController; 

    @Autowired
    ConsoleTabController consoleTabController;

    @Autowired
    DataModel datamodel;

    private double totalFileCount; // This is the value needed from task1
    private double completionCount; 

    private int importCount; // Total Number of Files that have been imported at the end of the task
    private int failCount;


    @Override
    public void run() {

        importCount = 0;
        failCount = 0;
        totalFileCount = fileBrowserController.getSelectedLeafCount();


        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

footerController.getTaskLabel().setText(footerController.IMPORTING_FILES_MSG);
                        footerController.getTaskProgressIndicator().setProgress(0.0);
                        footerController.getTaskProgressIndicator().setVisible(true);


            }

        });

        List<Song> importSongsList = new ArrayList<>();

        importSongsList = importFilesForImportButton(fileBrowserController.getFileBrowser().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems(), importSongsList);

        datamodel.getWindowDisplaySongs().addAll(importSongsList);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Reset button and progress bar values
                completionCount = 0;
            }

        });

    }


    private List<Song> importFilesForImportButton(List<TreeItem<File>> files, List<Song> importList){


        for(TreeItem<File> f : files) {     
            try {
                if(f.isLeaf() && !datamodel.songWindowContainsFile(f.getValue())) {

                    // Perform Processing 

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            footerController.getTaskProgressIndicator().setProgress((completionCount / totalFileCount)); // Need the value from task 1 here

                        }   
                    });
                    completionCount++;
                    importCount++;
                }else{
                    importFilesForImportButton(f.getChildren(), importList);
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return importList;
    }
}
```

**Additional Questions**

1. Is there any better performing solution to allow me to have a progress bar to update based on the total file count that wouldn't require me to go through all of the files 2 times (once to get the total count for the progress bar, and then a second to actually import them)?
2. Is there a way for me to start the task to count the leaf items from within the import task but make sure that the import task doesn't continue until the counting task is 100% complete? because I should only need to start that task from within other background tasks but I am not sure how to make sure that it completes first.

Comment: These two tasks should really be run in the same thread, so I would just combine them into a single task. Set the progress to [`INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS), count the files, then import them, updating the progress as you go. You could also just do `totalFileCount = new GetSelectedFilesLeafCountTask().call();` from within `ImportSongsTask.call()`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the response, both of your solutions worked! However, I was intending to re-use the leaf counting task again within in a few other tasks that use the same file browser tree selection items so I was trying to separate the tasks to make it reusable instead of including it's implementation in each task, would you still recommend that I do everything within the task or in this case should I just use the totalFileCount = new GetSelectedFilesLeafCountTask().call(); line of code in each task that needs to get a total count?